# SpringBoot: Загрузка Map с помощью аннотации @Value

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-boot

Файл `application.yml`

```
math:
  symbols:
    key1: asd
    key0: sdsss
```

Рабочий вариант класса, который использует эти данные:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "math")
class MathSymbolsTemplate {

    lateinit var symbols: Map<String, String>
}
```

Нерабочий вариант:

```
@Configuration
class MathSymbolsTemplate {

    @Value("\${math.symbols}")
    lateinit var symbols: Map<String, String>
}
```

Ошибки:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-05-25 01:17:06.513 ERROR 9516 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mathSymbolsTemplate': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'math.symbols' in value "${math.symbols}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.example.getbase.GetBaseApplicationKt.main(GetBaseApplication.kt:17) ~[main/:na]
    at org.example.getbase.GetBaseApplicationKt.main(GetBaseApplication.kt) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'math.symbols' in value "${math.symbols}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:191) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:936) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Вопрос, в общем-то, в следующем. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в разнице между рабочим вариантом и нерабочим (именно в плане инициализации конкретного свойства класса). И как все таки загрузить `Map` через аннотацию `@Value`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если отвечать по существу, то чтобы внедрить `Map` через `.yaml` нужно использовать вот такой синтаксис аннотации `@Value`:

```
@Value("#{${math.symbols}}") // Это язык Java, мб в Kotlin по-другому, у вас там какой то "\" ещё ставиться видимо
```

Так же преобразиться application.yaml:

```
math:
  symbols: '{
    key1: "asd",
    key0: "sdsss"
  }'
```

Почему? Потому что:

1. Аннотация `@Value` НЕ умеет работать со сложными структурами файла типа `.yaml` (`org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1330` - эта строчка кода вытаскивает из файла пропертей именно строку)
2. Даже если аннотации `@Value` предоставить `Map` в виде строки (как я сделал это выше), то она всё равно не сможет это обработать, так как в `Spring` нет преобразователя из `String` -> `Map` (возможно, его как то можно добавить, но я не в курсе)

Поэтому нужно НЕ ТОЛЬКО изменить структуру `.yaml` файла так, чтобы в ней хранились только строковые значение, но и использовать язык `SpEL` так как он умеет преобразовывать `String` -> `Map`

Если вдруг не понятен первый пункт, то объясняю: допустим, попробуем внедрить `List` и если пользоваться прелестями `.yaml`, то выглядеть это будет так:

```
math:
  symbols: 
    - key1
    - key0
```

А если нет, то так:

```
math:
  symbols: key1,key0
```

Так вот первый `.yaml` он вообще не считает и даже не найдет значения (будет как раз ошибка `Could not resolve placeholder 'math.symbols'` хотя казалось бы как так? Значение вроде есть!), а второй он прочитает и с помощью конструкции ниже внедрит значения

```
@Value("${math.symbols}")
private List<String> symbols;
```

А вот `@ConfigurationProperties` умеет работать с любыми структурами `.yaml` файла

P.S. `SpEL` - это та самая `#{}` перед `${}`

P.S.S. Я не нашёл документации к этому процессу, всё узнал из исходного кода Spring'a, поэтому если кто-то может это подкрепить ссылками, то милости прошу. Также, есть подозрения, что такой преобразователь в `Spring` действительно можно внедрить, но пока не знаю как.

Comment: Просто лучший! Спасибо! Если бы вы не оставили ответ, то я бы сам написал, но гораздо менее развернуто. В телеграмм-сообществе [Java, Spring Boot & Microservices](https://t.me/SpringBootMicroservices) нашел подсказку, что `@Value` умеет загружать только строки. При этом конструкция `symbols: key1,key0` хорошо преобразуется в `List`. С более сложными конструкциями - либо трудно, либо невозможно. Также в основной документации к Spring видел, что сами разработчики рекомендуют использовать `@ConfigurationProperties`.